# How to avoid systemd PID conflict after crash?

Tags: rhel, systemd, apache-httpd

I'm running `httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-7` configured to start on boot (via systemd) on RHEL 7.7. Recently I had this problem:

1. System crashed, leaving the `httpd.pid` file intact
2. System started back up
3. `httpd` start failed with a message like:

   > *httpd-scl-wrapper[119625]: httpd (pid 1440) already running*
4. Looking up PID 1440, I saw that it had been assigned to a different process
5. So, I needed to delete `httpd.pid` before `httpd` would start

Ideally all of our services would start back up after a crash without human intervention. Is there a good way to avoid/mitigate this scenario?

Comment: Configure httpd to store its PID file somewhere in `/tmp` or `/var/run` perhaps?

Comment: What does the systemd unit file for httpd look like?  Also, was that provided as part of the installation, or did you define it locally?

Comment: Related reading: [Don't create PID files](http://jdebp.eu/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotCreatePIDFiles).  (While that link is excellent advice for the *author* of a daemon, it doesn't solve an administrator's problem in dealing with a daemon that *did* create a PID file.  So doesn't directly solve your question, but still worth linking to.)

Comment: @111--- I think that's it! Our PID file is being stored in a custom directory; I didn't realize that the `/var/run` directories get blown away on boot, which would take care of this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Internet points should be awarded [for this answer in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548776/how-to-avoid-systemd-pid-conflict-after-crash?noredirect=1#comment1018588_548776).)*

The problem in our case was that we had set a custom `PidFile` location outside `/var/run`. Our custom location was not on a `tmpfs` file system, meaning that our `httpd.pid` would remain in place after a crash and restart. So, the solution is to store the PID file in a location like `/var/run` that gets reconstituted on system start.

**NOTE:** our `http24-httpd` is coming from RHSCL. By default, the process seems to want to store its PID file in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/run` which does **not** appear to be `tmpfs`.

Comment: This isn't a full solution. The HTTP Server may crash (or be aborted) all by itself, and then you'll have the same issue with a stale PID file when you try to restart it.

Comment: @AlexP I'd argue it is a full solution to my given scenario where the _host_ crashes, and I want Apache to autostart normally when the host recovers. You are of course right that the PID file would remain if Apache itself crashes, though that is so rare in my environment that I struggle to think of a single occurrence.